# kworker gets very high cpu usage only when USB is not plugged in

Tags: 15.10

I noticed that kworker gets very high (75%) when a USB port on my laptop is not used, as soon as I plug something in, it goes down to (0.5%).

Laptop: System76 Lemur (Lemu6)

Ubuntu 15.10 x64

Comment: nope, clean install

Comment: Have you checked dmesg for anything interesting? Maybe check once when it is high and once again after plugging in to compare.

Comment: nothing seems to change in the dmesg

Answer (score 1):

I have a Lemur with this same issue. Appears to be this bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1488426

Using kernel 4.4 (and the two headers packages) from here seems to work for me:
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4-wily

Update: I found better compatable kernels and updated the link.

Comment: Hey Jay, do you get any weird screen flickers while on the 4.4 kernel?

Comment: Sure (did)! The flicker is a problem with the drm-next kernel. I found out later that the kernels located here work better (and don't have the flicker):

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4-wily

I forgot to update my solution, so I just updated it with the better link.

Comment: you're a damn live safer man.